# Prove that log n! = n log n - O(n)

Tags: math, big-o, complexity-theory

So i have seen everywhere on how log n! = nlogn. I don't know how to get to O(n)

Textbook just says log(n!) = logn + log(n − 1) + ··· + log(1) = nlogn − O(n) but does not. explain.

Answer (score 2):

From `ln(x-1) < ln(floor(x)) ≤ ln(x)`, one deduces by integration from 1 to n+1

```
⌠              ⌠                   ⌠
⌡ ln(x-1).dx < ⌡ ln(floor(x)).dx ≤ ⌡ ln(x).dx
```

The integrand in the middle term is piecewise linear constant, and one easily sees that it is nothing but

```
Σ[1->n] ln(k) = ln(n!)
```

Finally,

```
n.ln(n)-n ≤ ln(n!) < (n+1)ln(n+1)-n
```

and

```
(n+1)ln(n+1) - n.ln(n) = n.ln(1+1/n) + ln(n+1) = O(n).
```